# sending signTransaction with web3.js. but I can't confirm this transaction in ganache

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, web3js, ganache

I want to put data in rawTransaction and send it to the smart contact of the ganache local node.
By the way, the raw transaction I made with the data was created, but I can't see the transaction on ganache. Why did you do that?

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545/'));
const Accounts = require('web3-eth-accounts');

let user_addr = "dummy addr"
let user_cash = "dummy cash"
let userInfo = [user_addr, user_cash];
let payment_user = web3.utils.toHex(userInfo);
console.log(payment_user);


web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
    from: "0xa22b061113adf71a54E9a12F7480256D8C342d8F",
    to: '0xEf938B9eCC089D47BAA7B4582Cdb69C526bfD827',
    value: '10000',
    gas: 200000,
    data: payment_user
}, '052607c87473b31777d0f208021da7b68949f0b02b09bcecb0248198dbed765d');
```

Result:

```
 messageHash: '0x4a2dbabb5a7a8e16102fef48f5f1e2154c266c14c3095033d5b3c496bc179e13',
  v: '0x0a95',
  r: '0xc01ea799c002a1eac82bd0aa1856ae5f86f6a74c6985ac74695fedcf55a755c3',
  s: '0x200fdb3e4f6013e9dcc9ed47ae28e0b95a7837498c9e173734312b616629a827',
  rawTransaction: '0xf884158504a817c80083030d4094ef938b9ecc089d47baa7b4582cdb69c526bfd8278227109b5b2264756d6d792061646472222c2264756d6d792063617368225d820a95a0c01ea799c002a1eac82bd0aa1856ae5f86f6a74c6985ac74695fedcf55a755c3a0200fdb3e4f6013e9dcc9ed47ae28e0b95a7837498c9e173734312b616629a827',
  transactionHash: '0xa71361fed8d1cb69cc67e801aa118a151ec50bcf3f1b95053af7258265e151c5'
```

ganache (These transactions are based on smart contract deploy) :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EnoY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no code to send a transaction whatsoever in your js file. All you did is that you signed a transaction with a private key. You can use [web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction) to send it.

Answer (score 0):

You need send this raw transaction to network.
let signed = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(...)

let tx = web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);

console.log('tx:', tx);